# Windows Server Web Application Proxy remove X-Frame-Options Header

Tags: windows-server, windows-server-2016, reverse-proxy

I have a web application that is published with Windows Server (2016) ADFS and Windows Server (2016) Web Application Proxy.
The login screen from ADFS always gets delivered with X-Frame-Options Header set to deny.
In ADFS I can control the X-Frame-Options Headers that are sent, for example I can disable them.

Web Application Proxy always sets X-Frame-Options to Deny.

How can I modify the X-Frame-Options Headers from Windows Server Web Application Proxy?

(I know that this setting is not optimal and potentially insecure but in my use case I need to display the application in an Iframe)